# Entity framework code first migration when data model as seperate project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have data model which I created using EF codefirst approach.First I created the model classes on my mvc application's Models folder and created my database from it working fine.
But now I want to add another project into my solution which uses the same model(database),so I created a class library project(BM.Core) and put my Models ,context class and Repository in that project and created another class library project(BM.Services) and put my all service classes in it which accesses the repository and model classes inside it.

Then I deleted my database from SSMS then enabled migration on my new Model project, BM.Core and  the database is created .But when I access the context in my Repository class I get the 
following error

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently

so I search on the google about this error and I got the solution from this  :[post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18c993be-c357-4c99-908e-f879f28c5ee0/the-context-cannot-be-used-while-the-model-is-being-created?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

and I put

```
ctx.Database.Initialize(force: false);
```

on my repositories constructor for while the application is working but when I rebuild my model project (BM.Core) I got the following error

> The model backing the 'BookManyContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

so I need to redone the migration and update-database procedure each time when I rebuild the model project but the funny thing about it is that the the Up and Down method of DbMigration is empty on migration.

I run the migration as by :

```
enable-migrations -contexttypename BookManyContext
add-migration InitialCreate3 
update-database
```

whats wrong with my code